# i want to allowed either null or integer value throw my jsp

Tags: html, jsp

```
var char1 = /^[0-9]+$/;
if (!($("#AcNo").val().match(char1))) {
    window.parent.showAlert('<s:text name="common.lbl.AcNo" /> <s:text name="common.msg.notValid" />');
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Kindly format your question and provide more details.

Comment: i want to allowed null also
how can i do please suggest ....

Comment: null value is not allowed here 
i want to allowed either null or integer

Answer (score 0):

**The value of a field can not be null, it's always a string value.**

You should check for empty string instead.

```
if ( $("#AcNo").val() != '' ){ 
    // your code here.
}
```

**OR**

```
if ( $("#AcNo").val().length != 0){
     // your code here.
}
```

To check for numeric values (that includes floats and integers )

```
$.isNumeric($("#AcNo").val())
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your comment. The following code checks if the value is not null and is an integer.

```
var value = $("#AcNo").val()
if( value != ''  &&  value % 1 === 0 ) {
  //do something
}
```